# What would be an efficient way to merge those lists?

Tags: scala, collections, functional-programming

Let's assume these four lists of String:

```
List("123::foo") 
List("456::bar") 
List("123::hello") 
List("456::scala")
```

What would be an efficient way to end up with:

```
List("123","foo","hello")
List("456","bar","scala")
```

and expected to work for a huge amount of initial Lists.

Comment: Efficient in what terms? Memory? CPU time? I am sorry to be too ironic, but if the number of lists is really unlimited then you can be sure that no algorithm will finish as long as we are alive. Let's provide some more reasonable assumptions. They really matter.

Comment: To be more constructive, I would create a mutable Map[String,List[String]] where key would be "123" and value is List("foo", "hello").

Comment: all the lists contain a single element?

Comment: @stew good point. @Mik378, if all the lists contain a single elemtent, why not create one list: `List("123::foo","456::bar","123::hello","456::scala")` ?

Comment: @Rado I just don't want to waste too memory or cpu, since I may have the case where there are 100 000 lists, for instance. "Unlimited", here is not the right word, "huge" could be adapted (updated).

Comment: @stew yes, all the list contains a single element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this ?

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_65).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>   val lists: List[List[String]] = List(List("123::foo"), List("456::bar"), List("123::hello"), List("456::scala"))
lists: List[List[String]] = List(List(123::foo), List(456::bar), List(123::hello), List(456::scala))

scala>   val result: List[List[String]] = lists.foldLeft(Map.empty[String, List[String]]) {
     |     (accumulator, nextList) =>
     |       nextList.headOption.map(_.split("::").toList).map { // next.headOption is safe in case of `lists` is empty
     |         case head :: last :: Nil => // matches only on those inner lists which have a single `::`
     |           accumulator.get(head) match {
     |             case None => accumulator + (head -> (last :: Nil)) // create a record in the map only if the key i.e., `head` is new
     |             case Some(xs) => accumulator + (head -> (last :: xs)) // If the key exists, prepend the new `last` to the existing value list
     |           }
     |         case _ => accumulator // for all the other case matches, just return the so far accumulated map
     |       }.getOrElse(accumulator) // exits as a base case for 1. If the `lists` is empty 2. If the `lists` is run over completely
     |   }.collect { case (str, xs) => str :: xs }.toList // getting it to the List[List[String]] type
result: List[List[String]] = List(List(123, hello, foo), List(456, scala, bar))
```

Comment: Venkat, could you walk us through the logic. It looks like it will deal with data "variations" more cleanly, and certainly performs well.

Comment: @wwkudu My pleasure to add comments :) Hope this helps in understanding the logic.

Comment: Sweet. It performs in roughly half the time of my approach. I like that it intelligently accumulates. Learning something new with collect. Nice.

Comment: @wwkudu The beauty of foldLeft is it is tail-recursive in the Std. Scala Library. Thanks for taking time benchmark both the tests.

Comment: @Venkat If I valid this answer, you'll exceed "271"..can I? :) ;)

Comment: Smart way, I like it :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using a couple of assumptions (single string in each list, two subitems separated by the string "::"), I came up with the following:

```
  for (
    i <- lists.map(_.head.split("::").toList) //-- extract sub items from each string
      .groupBy(_(0))  //-- group into a map by first item
      .values  //-- and work with just the value lists
  ) yield i.flatten //-- create new collection with flattened version of each list
    .toSet //-- where the duplicates are removed 
    .toList //-- and return finally a list again
```

As to efficiency, I can really only speak empirically - about 4 seconds for a 100,000 item initial list. Someone more familiar with Scala collection methods can help optimise or comment on it's efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from the sample what the order resulting values is: the order in which they appear or the sorted order by keys.

Assuming the resulting order is based on

- keys are sorted
- values have the order in which they appear

Scala code:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.TreeMap

object temp {
  val lists = List(
    List("123::foo"),
    List("456::bar"),
    List("123::hello"),
    List("456::scala"))

  // construct groups keyed by first value after a "::" split
  // construct a TreeMap, perhaps we can optimize here
  val res = TreeMap(
    (lists map (_.head) map (_.split("::")) groupBy (_(0)))
      .toSeq: _*) 
    .map { x => List(x._1) ++ (x._2 map (_(1))) }

  //> List(List(123, foo, hello), List(456, bar, scala))

}
```

Comment: A small note: If the list does not have a String which contains `::`, groupBy(_(0)) will blow-up with java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @VenkatSudheerReddyAedama: Agreed. The code is based on the input provided by OP.

Comment: As a note, this method performs (very) roughly as fast as that of @user3189923 but without the additional heap space requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Using string pattern matching groups,

```
implicit class RichListAssociation(val in: List[List[String]]) extends AnyVal {
  def assoc(pattern: String = """(\d+)::(\w+)""") = {
    val pat = pattern.r       
    val pairs = in.par.map{ case List(s,_*) => val pat(a,b) = s ; (a,b) }.groupBy(_._1)    
    pairs.par.map{ case (k,v) => k :: v.map{_._2}.toList  }
  }
}
```

For

```
val in = List(
    List("123::foo"),
    List("456::bar"),
    List("123::hello"),
    List("456::scala"))
```

a call

```
in.assoc()
```

gives

```
List(List(456, bar, scala), List(123, foo, hello))
```

Pattern matching may prove convenient for specialised string extraction. Performance unclear in this approach, yet for input strings worth using one list with listed strings more than nested lists.

Comment: Interestingly the fastest on my very simple test, but this one takes the most heap space.

Comment: Many Thanks for considering this answer :) As of heap space, last two lines in def assoc may be refactored onto a view so as to minimise intermediate results, in case it becomes a difficulty due to large input list(s).

Comment: Efficiency can be improved with par.map specially for large lists (first map occurrence in last two lines in def assoc).